# How to check the directory structure of a docker tar archive？

Tags: docker, cloud

The case is some users use `docker save` to get image archives and they send them to me. I would want to know the directory structure of that archive. For example if there is  /var , /root and /home/somefiles directories in an image? If I don't use `docker load  xxx.tar` and `docker run`, how to check the directory structure of the docker tar archive? Because I need to add some files to specified path in the image.

Comment: you can add the files and create your desired path regardless

Comment: thank you @Ijaz Khan.May be I didn't describe it clearly. Actually I need check the directory structure of the container. Is there any methods instead of using `docker load xxx.tar` and `docker run -it  xxx` to check?

Answer (score 1):

The `docker save`/`docker load` format is [lightly documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ImageGet); I've run across very few tools that actually manipulate it in any form.

If you just want to add something to the image contents, then the best way is to `docker load` it and then use a Dockerfile as normal

```
FROM image:from-the-tar-file
COPY a_file.txt /
```

Otherwise, the tar file contains a directory per layer in the image, and each of those directories contains a `layer.tar` file with the actual layer contents.  You'd have to write your own tool to inspect this, but you could use something like [the Python tarfile library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) to look inside the file without fully expanding it.

Here's a quick Python script that checks if any layer in a `docker save` tar file contains a shell:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import tarfile

def main():
    with tarfile.open(sys.argv[1]) as outer:
        layers_tars = [n for n in outer.getnames() if n.endswith('/layer.tar')]
        for layer_tar in layers_tars:
            layer_file = outer.extractfile(layer_tar)
            if layer_file is None:
                continue
            with tarfile.open(fileobj=layer_file) as layer:
                if 'bin/sh' in layer.getnames():
                    print(layer_tar)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Modifying and reassembling the save file is tricky; I've never done it successfully.  There are a couple of JSON files that don't have a well-specified format in the documentation, and it's not 100% clear what happens when layers aren't fully additive (a layer removes a file that was in a lower layer).

Answer (score 1):

I used what @lewo explained.

```bash
tar -xvf your-docker-image-as-a-tar-file
mkdir layers
cd layers
tar -xvf ../fdb124a038a8622f9a7028709f88ssbf695df7db9j9760d28e56bd5cde29e3e8/layer.tar
```

I repeated the last line as many times as the number of layers,
and in the end I got this

```bash
user@vm:~/docker-image-filesystem/layer$ ls
bin  dev  etc  home  lib  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the Docker image archive contains all layers which are also `tar` file. I don't think you can inpect easily nesteed tar file with the tar tools: you would first need to untar the Docker archive and then `tar -tf` all layers.

Maybe, we could use `skopeo` which can "copy" a docker archive to a  dir:

```
skopeo copy docker-archive://image.tgz dir:///tmp/image
```

Comment: thank you @Iewo.May be I didn't describe it clearly. Actually I need check the directory structure of the container. Is there any methods instead of using `docker load xxx.tar` and `docker run -it  xxx` to check?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on Docker storage driver. For the latest recommended `overlay2` it could be done like this:

For example I have a running ubuntu container:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2bfe549061f0        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                            keen_lewin
```

Next you can inspect your container for searching its data:

```
$ docker inspect 2bfe549061f0
...
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/39d10569b3d2543b9517c008e2244e1abde19aa3ec482ba0854cbdd332441e28-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/32515dae6c1711b05d726b1cd4856f7df3a24a5beb36b412eec7713e1965ce7a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b74326fdacfa1e713b567d286e76077f12f357d92a7c5418a850db5b78fb9d2b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b14f98b9aefba75ba8d36005833eb4a9ec9aea84358756e753f7cd480d2c7c1a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c3432c55caac2d52d2715624bece08daa309e8df0ba5207399b369d09bd6b360/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b81022c8b19d25f3bd88329ddade8dab337809fc90429c691df5e314bc773320/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/39d10569b3d2543b9517c008e2244e1abde19aa3ec482ba0854cbdd332441e28/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/39d10569b3d2543b9517c008e2244e1abde19aa3ec482ba0854cbdd332441e28/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/39d10569b3d2543b9517c008e2244e1abde19aa3ec482ba0854cbdd332441e28/work"
...
```

Long story short: the "clear" image will be stored at the last path in `LowerDir` key. In my case it is the path:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b81022c8b19d25f3bd88329ddade8dab337809fc90429c691df5e314bc773320/diff 
    total 76
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:45 bin
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 апр 24 14:34 boot
    drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 dev
    drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 4096 мая 26 06:45 etc
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 апр 24 14:34 home
    drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 lib
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 lib64
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 media
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 mnt
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 opt
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 апр 24 14:34 proc
    drwx------  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:45 root
    drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 run
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:45 sbin
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 srv
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 апр 24 14:34 sys
    drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4096 мая 26 06:45 tmp
    drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 мая 26 06:44 usr
    drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 мая 26 06:45 var

# Enusre it is Ubuntu 18.04
$ sudo cat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b81022c8b19d25f3bd88329ddade8dab337809fc90429c691df5e314bc773320/diff/etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

If I create something within a container, e.g.

```
root@2bfe549061f0:/# echo 123 > check_file.txt
```

Changes could be found in the `UpperDir`:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/docker/overlay2/39d10569b3d2543b9517c008e2244e1abde19aa3ec482ba0854cbdd332441e28/diff
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 окт 23 15:25 check_file.txt

$ sudo cat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/39d10569b3d2543b9517c008e2244e1abde19aa3ec482ba0854cbdd332441e28/diff/check_file.txt
123
```

The similar things could be done without any running containers via

`docker image inspect <IMAGE>`

More info:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#image-and-container-layers-on-disk